# Paste data from Excel and convert into an array?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I'm new powershell and want to take a list of servers from Excel, and literally paste into an input window. It should segregate it and process it one after other.

ie
give the name of servers:

```
arvdel1
arvdel2
arvdel3
arvdel4
```

and it should take it as

```
$a=@(arvdel1,arvdel2,arvdel3,arvdel4)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [Read-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-3.0)?

Comment: I'd use a comma separated server list as input: `$a = (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter servers (comma separated)").Split(',')`

Comment: You could also read the clipboard content with `Get-Clipboard`, see `Get-Help Get-Clipboard`. Your choice of tags is ambiguous, PSv2 usually excludes the other - hover of the tag labels to read the tag info..

Comment: no i want to copy paste from excel to prompt and it should split it by commas to take it as array

Comment: @Phoenix2529 Then it's LotPings approach

Comment: Might well be easier to [read the data from the Excel file](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$cli= Read-Host("Enter the servers")
$a=$cli.Replace("`n",",")
$b=$a.split(",")
foreach($i in $b)
{
write-host " hi"
}

o/p:

Enter the servers: 1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
 hi
 hi
 hi

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are after.

- You simply can't paste an excel cell range into the powershell console prompt without getting a bunch of errors.
- A PowerShell script ***could*** wait at an own prompt to accept input,

  - 1st problem here is that a single input (`Read-Host`) will be terminated by a `cr/lf` sequence what is what excel uses to separate adjacent **ROWs**. So you will need a loop to catch all pasted ROWs. 2nd problem is you don't know when all rows are processed.
  - When copying a range with multiple columns they are <kbd>TAB</kbd> separated

---

To process unknwon clipboard(text) content either with multiplte cols/rows I'd use (as suggested in the comments) `Get-Clipboard` and use the RegEx based split operator with OR to split by either a <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>CR/LF</kbd>

[image: paste excel columns]

```
> (Get-Clipboard) -split '\t|\r?\n'
arvdel1
arvdel2
arvdel3
arvdel4
```

[image: paste excel rows]

```
> (Get-Clipboard) -split '\t|\r?\n'
arvdel1
arvdel2
arvdel3
arvdel4
```

[image: paste excel clumns and rows]

```
> (Get-Clipboard) -split '\t|\r?\n'
arvdel1
arvdel2
arvdel3
arvdel4
arvdel2
C3
D3
E3
arvdel3
C4
D4
E4
arvdel4
C5
D5
E5
```

Instead of outputting to the console you can of course assign to a variable or directly append a `ForEach-Object` to process them.

**Edit: an alternative reading the above excel file directly from PowerShell**
using [DFinke's ImportExcel module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel):

```
> import-excel .\Data.xlsx

ServersCol
----------
arvdel1
arvdel2
arvdel3
arvdel4
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.My script will take input from clipboard in form of array and execute any command for each server.All i have to do is copy any number of servers from notepad and run the script
Sample:
$d = @(Get-Clipboard)
foreach ($i in $d)
     {
     Write-Output "Hi"
     }

Answer (score 1):

You can use a required parameter (for Powershell versions less than 5.1 or 'Get-Clipboard' for version 5.1 or greater) that has type of String array [string[]]. It will prompt you for to enter the value of each array element until it detects a blank line that is entered.

I figured this out recently by looking at the input Parameters of a script. For years I was manipulating the text into the PowerShell single line array format with Excel's transpose and replacing 'Tab' characters in Notepad.

Just for reference PowerShell single line array format is ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

```
...
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string[]]
    $listOfStrings
)
...
```

Example prompt to fill to a string array

```
Supply values for the following parameters:
listOfStrings[0]:
```

I created a list in Notepad (or Excel) of 1 through 5 and directly copied it into PowerShell window. Below is my sample output.

```
1
2
3
4
5

Supply values for the following parameters:
listOfStrings[0]: 1
listOfStrings[1]: 2
listOfStrings[2]: 3
listOfStrings[3]: 4
listOfStrings[4]: 5
listOfStrings[5]:
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the pieces you need:

```
try {
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open('E:\Temp\Data.xlsx')
    $xlSheet = $excel.Sheets.Item('Sheet1')
    $a = @($xlSheet.Range("A1:A4").Value2)
    #prefered to use named range
    #$xlSheet.Range("Items").Value2
} finally {
    $workbook.Close()
    $excel.Quit()
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
}

$a | sort | % {
  #process
  "Processing: $_"
}
```

*Edit:*
To split string use -split:

```
'arvdel1,arvdel2,arvdel3,arvdel4' -split ','
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in scripts that require pasting a list of computer names:

```
$MultilineInput = Read-Host "Enter List of Computer Names"

$PCQueryList = @"
$MultilineInput
"@ -split '\r\n'
```

To confirm your pasted list are unique objects, run a $PCQueryList.count and $MultilineInput.count

arvdel1
arvdel2
arvdel3
arvdel4

$ $PCQueryList.count
4

$ $MultilineInput
1